# mode notebook code migration to Google Notebook

Tags: google-colaboratory, looker-studio, google-cloud-datalab, mode-analytics

I have python code executed in Mode 'Python Notebook' and want to migrate the code to Google Cloud Platform.I am using Google Bigquery to load the data in database.
I have found Google DataLab and CoLab(Colaboratory) as an best alternative.Does Jupyter Notebook perform better than these tools?
But my issue is I want to migrate this code one of these tool and visualize this data in Google Data Studio.Is this Possible to visualize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a good explanation of Cloud Datalab and Colaboratory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340602/google-colaboratory-vs-google-datalab-how-are-they-different).

Jupyter Notebook allows you for visualizing data directly in the created notebook, thanks to the Python libraries. There is no need to use Data Studio for that. Please, take a look for the following [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/visualize-jupyter).

If you decide for Google Colaboratory, it can be easily integrated with Data Studio, i.e. you can save predictions from Colab as a Google Sheet, and Google Data Studio will display the data from it on the dashboard. Google Data Studio can connect multiple data sources for reporting. Please, have a look for the following [documentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/build-predictive-business-intelligence-with-google-colab-google-data-studio-and-google-sheets-9a5c1559124f).

Comment: Thanks....i have exported the python code from Mode Notebook but its saved in .py format.i think DataLab and CoLab supports .pynb format..how to overcome this issue?

Comment: Please, take a look for the following thread on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510114/converting-from-py-to-ipynb). Additionally, there is Python [library](https://pypi.org/project/ipynb-py-convert/#:~:text=Atom%2FHydrogen%20or%20VSCode%2FPython,%2C%20Atom%2FHydrogen%20Getting%20Started.) that can help you overcome the issue.

Comment: Another question...Can i get the python code output in Data Studio similarly like pandas data frame?